# Convert MongoDB aggregation query to kotlin

Tags: mongodb, kotlin

I have below mongodb query, need to convert it to the kotlin spring data. Can any one help me this:

```
db.sensor_polling_logs.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {"logItems.houseId": 123677}
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$logItems"
    },
    {
        $match: {"logItems.houseId": 123677}
    },
    
    {
        $sort: {addedAt: -1}
    },
    {
        $limit: 50
    },
       { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: {
           text: "$logItems.text",
           measurementSourceId: "$logItems.measurementSourceId",
           success: "$logItems.success",
           systemObjectId: "$systemObjectId" 
       } } }
    ])
```

Comment: Try following the examples in [the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/fundamentals/aggregation/). If you encounter issues with writing it, you can post what you ended up with here, and you'll have much greater chances of getting a response.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get the code from an Aggregation Pipeline would be to use [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) (free)

As you can see in this screen capture, after connecting to your DB and running your pipeline you can export it to several languages. Kotlin is not included (yet) but you can export to Java, then convert into Kotlin.

[image: Export Pipeline To Language screen from Compass, where a Pipeline is transformed into Java Code]